# iOS app crashs only after opening it. New Build

Tags: ios, iphone

My app is crashing after opening it, please any idea ?

I am testing my iOS app on my phone and when I try opening it, it instantly exits. App builds and works in simulator or if I run through xCode. Does anyone know what could be the cause?

```
default 23:34:28.298271 +0300   SpringBoard Running <SBAppToAppWorkspaceTransaction: 0x10c501e00> for transition request:
<SBMainWorkspaceTransitionRequest: 0x1c56e8e00; eventLabel: SBUIApplicationIconLaunchEventLabel; display: Main; source: HomeScreen> {
    applicationContext = <SBWorkspaceApplicationSceneTransitionContext: 0x1c43510f0; background: NO> entities = {
        SBLayoutRolePrimary = <SBDeviceApplicationSceneEntity: 0x1c46988d0; ID: com.myapp; layoutRole: primary>;
    };
}
default 23:34:28.312181 +0300   assertiond  Submitting new job for "com.myapp" on behalf of <BKProcess: 0x100a0cda0; SpringBoard; com.apple.springboard; pid: 55; agency: SystemShell; visibility: foreground; task: running>
default 23:34:28.312373 +0300   assertiond  Submitted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.myapp[0x5e0f][66]
default 23:34:28.429755 +0300   assertiond  Now tracking process <BKProcess: 0x100b482b0; Real Agent; com.myapp; pid: 386; agency: Application; visibility: none; task: running; hostpid: 55> with host <BKProcess: 0x100a0cda0; SpringBoard; com.apple.springboard; pid: 55; agency: SystemShell; visibility: foreground; task: running>
default 23:34:28.434511 +0300   SpringBoard [com.myapp] Bootstrap complete with label: UIKitApplication:com.myapp[0x5e0f][66]
default 23:34:28.436639 +0300   SpringBoard [FBProcessManager] Adding: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10c510250; Real Agent (com.myapp); pid: 386>
default 23:34:28.444373 +0300   SpringBoard WIFI PICKER [com.myapp]: isProcessLaunch: 1,    isForegroundActivation: 1,     isForegroundDeactivation: 0
default 23:34:28.517241 +0300   mediaserverd    -CMSessionMgr- CMSessionMgrHandleApplicationStateChange: CMSession: Client com.myapp with pid '386' is now Foreground Running. Background entitlement: YES
default 23:34:28.522407 +0300   SpringBoard [com.myapp] Setting deactivation reasons to: 'systemAnimation' for reason: scene settings update - settings are eligible for deactivation reasons.
default 23:34:28.534346 +0300   SpringBoard [com.myapp] Setting deactivation reasons to: '(none)' for reason: updateAllScenesForBand - Assertion removed.
default 23:34:28.638341 +0300   SpringBoard Application process state changed for com.myapp: <SBApplicationProcessState: 0x1c42301c0; pid: 386; taskState: Running; visibility: Unknown>
default 23:34:28.736365 +0300   symptomsd   386 com.myapp: ForegroundRunning (most elevated: ForegroundRunning)
error   23:34:28.736560 +0300   symptomsd   Attempt to add an app with insufficient id, info {
    BKSApplicationStateAppIsFrontmost = 1;
    BKSApplicationStateExtensionKey = 0;
    SBApplicationStateDisplayIDKey = "com.myapp";
    SBApplicationStateKey = 8;
    SBApplicationStateProcessIDKey = 386;
    SBMostElevatedStateForProcessID = 8;
}
default 23:34:29.453786 +0300   assertiond  Process exited: <BKProcess: 0x100b482b0; Real Agent; com.myapp; pid: 386; agency: Application; visibility: foreground; task: none; hostpid: 55>
default 23:34:29.779352 +0300   SpringBoard <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10c510250; Real Agent (com.myapp); pid: 386> crashed.
default 23:34:29.779441 +0300   assertiond  Deleted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.myapp[0x5e0f][66]
default 23:34:29.783121 +0300   SpringBoard [FBProcessManager] Removing: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10c510250; Real Agent (com.myapp); pid: -1>
default 23:34:29.784062 +0300   assertiond  [Real Agent:386] Deleted launchd job with label: UIKitApplication:com.myapp[0x5e0f][66]
default 23:34:29.785372 +0300   SpringBoard WIFI PICKER [com.myapp]: isProcessLaunch: 0,    isForegroundActivation: 0,     isForegroundDeactivation: 1
default 23:34:29.786566 +0300   SpringBoard Front display did change: <SBApplication: 0x1c43c4470; com.myapp>
default 23:34:29.789791 +0300   SpringBoard [com.myapp] Setting deactivation reasons to: 'systemAnimation' for reason: updateAllScenesForBand - Assertion added.
default 23:34:29.795982 +0300   SpringBoard [com.myapp] Setting deactivation reasons to: 'appSwitcher, systemAnimation' for reason: updateAllScenesForBand - Assertion added.
default 23:34:29.797861 +0300   mediaserverd    -CMSessionMgr- CMSessionMgrHandleApplicationStateChange: CMSession: Client com.myapp with pid '386' is now Terminated. Background entitlement: NO
default 23:34:29.810557 +0300   SpringBoard [com.myapp] Will update scene - foregroundness changed to: Background
default 23:34:29.810662 +0300   SpringBoard [com.myapp] Setting deactivation reasons to: '(none)' for reason: scene settings update - settings are NOT eligible for deactivation reasons.
default 23:34:29.818875 +0300   assertiond  Checking for deferred bootstrap request for com.myapp
default 23:34:29.849094 +0300   SpringBoard Process exited: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10c510250; Real Agent (com.myapp); pid: -1> -> <FBApplicationProcessExitContext: 0x1c0830c00; exitReason: crash; terminationReason: (none)>
default 23:34:29.849356 +0300   SpringBoard Application process state changed for com.myapp: (null)
default 23:34:29.986805 +0300   symptomsd   386 com.myapp: Terminated (most elevated: Terminated)
default 23:34:29.987061 +0300   symptomsd   Entry, display name com.myapp uuid (null) pid 386 isFront 0
```

Comment: How long ago did you install the app on the device?  Do you have a paid or free membership of the developer program?

Comment: I've been deleting, building, archiving, installing again and again through HockeyApp. Free membership.

Comment: It looks like you have reached your free membership limit for running disconnected.

Comment: My program type is: "Apple Developer Program"

Comment: But if you haven't paid the $99 fee, then there are limitations on how many apps you can deploy and how long they will run for

Comment: The Expiration Date of my Apple Developer Program is: November 12, 2019.

Comment: Hi! Do you solve the problem? I'm facing something similar to the described.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71872905/5179979