# tvOS app crashes without launching when no internet connection

Tags: swift, tvos, xcode13.3

I get this alert from XCODE:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Transaction's process
> <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10155d170; application:> is not
> running:  <FBApplicationUpdateScenesTransaction: 0x282f1a3a0>
> Completed: NO ClientIdentity: application Waits for scene commits: YES
> Interruptible? YES Milestones pending: (none) Audit history:  TIME:
> 13:29:25.024; DESCRIPTION: Life assertion taken for reason: beginning
> TIME: 13:29:25.024; DESCRIPTION: State changed from 'Initial' to
> 'Working' TIME: 13:29:25.024; DESCRIPTION: Life assertion removed for
> reason: beginning Concurrent child transactions:
> <FBApplicationProcessLaunchTransaction: 0x282911c00> Completed: NO
> Process: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10155d170; application:>
> Interruptible? YES Milestones pending:  processWillBeginLaunching
> processDidFinishLaun

Comment: cannot launch app

Answer (score 1):

Failure of Application launch can be of following reasons:

1. Any hanging threads initialised before launch
2. please review custom Dispatch queues initializtion or any custom classes
   that create DispatchQueues, Operation Queue etc

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was due to having the Apple TV configured for using Charles proxy. I was trying to run the app while the proxy application was not running on my Mac. So, it was as if the Apple TV was without an internet connection.

Comment: Today it happened again to me, simply because I had not configured a network on the Apple TV for the location where I was testing it.

So, please check you have an Internet connection on the Apple TV, that's the main reason.